# change date format mm-dd-yy and mm-dd-yyyy in same dataset

Tags: r, date

my data set contains a birth date column where som dates are mm-dd-yy and mm-dd-yyyy. e.g 11/24/87 and 11/24/1987

how can I change it to a correct format in mm-dd-yyyy?
i try this code

```
mutate(DOB = as.Date(DOB, format="%m/%d/%y"))
```

my goal in the end it to calculate the age of a person

thanks in advance

Comment: df$ddate <- format(as.Date(df$ddate), "%d/%m/%Y") Try this once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`'s `mdy` :

```
lubridate::mdy(c('11/24/87', '11/24/1987'))
#[1] "1987-11-24" "1987-11-24"
```

If your dataframe is called `df`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(DOB = mdy(DOB))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date` from `base R`

```
df <- transform(df, DOB = as.Date(DOB, "%m/%d/%y"))
```